# When I try to open a Torrent file, I get the message: Skipping unknown Torrent

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

While there was one active torrent, I tried starting another torrent I had downloaded. But, this next torrent did not open.

Even after completion of previous torrent, when I tried opening the it again, an empty Transmission window opens, but the Torrent does not.

Then, I ran it in the terminal and received the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the other torrent file is a fake. What is the output of `file name.torrent`? Also, do not post images of programs windows with text. Instead, copy/paste the text itself.

Comment: Please don't include a picture of text, provide the text.  Have you looked at what type of file it is?  (ie. `file blah`)  (*I can't copy/paste from a picture; so replace blah with the the name of the file in your picture*)